# Create a comment box using Rmarkdown (HTML file)

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I have an issue about creating a comment box (similar to the fbox if we want to output a PDF). The following code works for PDF file but not HTML.

```
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{48em}
...
\end{minipage}}
```

Could someone offer me some suggestions how to create a decent comment box for Rmarkdown HTML file? Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easiest way is to use predefined bootstrap elements like the following:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <strong>Info!</strong> Indicates a neutral informative change or action.
</div>
```

For details check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp).

Or you could simply use paragraph tags for the boxes and style them yourself using a CSS class:

```
---
title: "Comment Box"
output: html_document
---

<style>
p.comment {
background-color: #DBDBDB;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
margin-left: 25px;
border-radius: 5px;
font-style: italic;
}

</style>


### Bootstrap Alert

<div class="alert alert-info">
  <strong>Info!</strong> Indicates a neutral informative change or action.
</div>

### Custom Psragraphs

<p class="comment">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thanks for your help!! It improves my R tutorial files a a lot~~~~

Comment: Well, since I tried to change the attributes such as border: 1px solid black; to 10px, and red, but it does not work as expected. I wanna know how could I change the width and the color of the border. Also, I tried to make some of the text boldface inside the comment box, but it does not work as well. Could you offer me suggestions how to solve the problem? Thanks so much.

Comment: Using `border: 10px solid red;` works just fine. Also using `**Bold Text**`or `<strong>Bold Text</strong>` yield the expected results...

Comment: Note that for single use, [the style can be inlined](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp), avoiding the need to create a class.